# MongoError: no geo indices for geoNear

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geojson

Just now I started learning nodejs and am experimenting with GeoJson data.
I am trying to find all the ninjas within 100000m of the passed coordinates.
For each ninja model I am storing its coordinates in db.

But when I try to make the get request, I get this error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: no geo indices for
>   geoNear
>       at queryCallback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NodeJs\Node Rest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:248:25)
>       at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NodeJs\Node Rest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:532:18
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

My code-

```
router.get('/ninjas', function(req, res){

Ninja.aggregate().near({
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(req.query.lng),parseFloat(req.query.lat)] },
    maxDistance: 10000,  // in 10k meters
    spherical: true,
    distanceField: "dist.calculated"
  }).then(function(ninjas){
      console.log(ninjas)
    res.send(ninjas)
  });
});
```

My Schema-

```
const GeoSchema= new Schema({
type:{
    type:String,
    default:"Point"
},

coordinates:{
    type:[Number],
    index:"2dSphere"
}
})

const NinjaSchema= new Schema({
name:{type: String,
required:[true,"Name is required"]

},

rank:{
type:String

},
available:{
type:Boolean,
default:false
},

geometry:GeoSchema
});


const Ninja= mongoose.model('ninja', NinjaSchema);

module.exports= Ninja
```